# Excel convert [h]:mm:ss to a decimal format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have this cell with an [h]:mm:ss format, and would like to have minutes only, with 2 decimals after the coma (and not seconds).

For example:

A1: 2551:26:38

becomes

B1: 153086,63

How do I do that?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I got it:

B1 should have "General" as a cell format, and the formula below:

> =CONVERT(A1;"hr";"mn")*24